# Query for # of new user per week - how to order by year/week?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm working to write a MySQL query that outputs the number of new users created by week.

**My user table is:**

```
id | created_at
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT YEAR(created_at) AS Year, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%b %e') AS Week, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM users
GROUP BY Year, Week;
```

**The problem:**

- Years: I would like the most recent year to be at the top, currently the oldest year is at the top of the output.
- Weeks: The week column is not sorted based on the calendar. For example, the last records shows: `2019 | May 9 | 100`

Where I'd like the year and week sorted.

Comment: Have you looked into the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: You're not grouping by week, you're grouping by day.

Comment: Within the year, do you want the most recent week first or last?

Comment: @Barmar by year, the most recent first... thanks

Comment: I know you want the most recent year first, but do you want the most recent week or the first week of the year first?

Comment: the most recent week, to answer the question, how are we doing this week, how did we do last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find the function `YEARWEEK()` helpful, not only for the grouping, but also for the ordering.

Also, your use of `DATE_FORMAT()` doesn't look right, because you're outputing the `%e`, which is the day of the month, yet you're grouping by week?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y %b %v') AS date, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM users
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(created_at)
ORDER BY YEARWEEK(created_at) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks but that outputs the week funky like so: 201928, 201927, 201926

Comment: Is there a way to make this output friendlier?

Comment: What output did you actually want? `<year> <month> <week>`? You can't really include the day as per your original query, because which of the seven days of the week do you choose?

Comment: Thanks but the rows are not grouped by week, they have some strange ordering going on: 2019 Jul 28
2019 Jul 27
2019 Jun 26
2019 Jun 25
2019 Jun 24
2019 Jun 23
2019 Jun 22
2019 May 21
2019 May 20
2019 May 19
2019 May 18
2019 Apr 17
2019 Apr 16
2019 Apr 15
2019 Apr 14
2019 Mar 13
2019 Mar 12
2019 Mar 11
2019 Mar 10
2019 Mar 09
2019 Feb 08
2019 Feb 07
2019 Feb 06
2019 Feb 05
2019 Jan 04
2019 Jan 03
2019 Jan 02
2019 Jan 01
2018 Dec 52
2018 Dec 51
2018 Dec 50
2018 Dec 49
2018 Dec 48
2018 Nov 48
2018 Nov 46
2018 Nov 46
2018 Nov 44
2018 Oct 43
2018 Oct 43

Comment: That is outputting `<year> <month> <week of year>`. So the 27th and 28th week of the year are in July, the 23rd, 24th, 25th, and 26th weeks of the year are in June, etc...

Comment: Thanks but this is super confusing... How can we make this friendlier: 2019-07-7, 2019-07-14, 2019-07-21, 2019-07-28

Comment: You're going to need to explain your requirements in more detail. Each month doesn't start on the same day, so you're not going to get consistent _friendlier_ numbers. What day of the week do you want to use? The Monday, the Sunday? Have you tried to fix this last part yourself? Where are you stuck?